# Sending email from ASP.NET application using SMTP server in IIS6; email gets sent without error but the mail gets stuck in mailroot\drop folder

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-6

I have a SMTP server set up for my domain in IIS6.  The mail sends just fine from the site, there are no errors.  But the email is never delivered to the recipient.  I checked my mail folder on the server and the emails are stuck in \inetpub\mailroot\drop

Any idea why they wouldn't be getting sent out?  This is new territory for me and I'm not having much luck finding a solution.

Since the mail is making its way into the mail folder, I assume the problem lies somewhere in my SMTP server settings

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of reasons for this and it sounds to me that your provider has blocked port 25 which means your server can't send the emails, hence, they are still in the queue.

Your best bet is to use a 3rd party SMTP service such as Amazon SES or Mandrill (free), you can either configure your application to send mail directly through these providers, or, you can continue to use IIS SMTP and configure smart host, this will tell IIS SMTP to not bother trying to send email directly, but instead relay it through the 3rd party SMTP service.

More about SMTP and smart hosts here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303734/en-us